# Case statement with an ignoring condition postgres 9.3

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, case, postgresql-9.3

In my application the following abbreviation allows me to input a value and choose its type within the application e.g.

```
:input
```

in this case I created a variable

```
:Lang1 as a varchar
```

I have the following code simply asking how many speak a particular language from an array using a case statement

What I want to know is how many students know a language from an array and to check against the input field if it has a value inside it or not

```
(Case When Length(:Lang1)>4    --I'm assuming any language has more than 4 letters
then languages[1] = :Lang1     --When this condition statement is true then I get the children 
                   --and the number of children speaking the entered language as a 1st language
else (ignore condition) end)   --Simply trying to ignore the else side of the condition
```

I tried this code

```
(Case When Length(:Lang1)>4 then languages[1] = :Language 
else cast(:Lang1 as varchar(20)) end)
```

*ERROR: CASE types character varying and boolean cannot be matched*

and this code

```
(Case When Length(:Lang1)>4 then languages[1] = :Language 
end)
```

which produced a bunch 0 0 0s

This post is related to its former predecessors 
[Part 2: how to get the Sum of a partition based query without actually pivoting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50605639/part-2-how-to-get-the-sum-of-a-partition-based-query-without-actually-pivoting) and is placed in the following area

```
JOIN schoollevel sl ON sl.id = p.schoollevelid
GROUP BY s.studentnumber, p.firstname
 ) t
Where (Case When Length(:Lang1)>4 then languages[1] = :Lang1
    else cast(:Lang1 as varchar(20)) end)
)
select *
```

Comment: Are you writing an SQL query or a PL/pgSQL function. All the code you posted has so many syntactical problems that I don't understand what you want. Can you post more of your code so that it is possible to understand what you want?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Part 2: how to get the Sum of a partition based query without actually pivoting
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50605639/part-2-how-to-get-the-sum-of-a-partition-based-query-without-actually-pivoting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `case` expression returns a value, not a fragment of syntax you can use as a condition. You could instead use the `or` logical operator to create this logic:

```
WHERE LENGTH(:Lang1) <= 4 OR languages[1] = :Lang1
```