# PostgreSql 9.5 for CUBE

Tags: postgresql, olap, cube, olap-cube

I have installed PostgreSQL 9.5.13 version. I want to use the function CUBE for a data warehouse. So for testing, I have created a table called "sales":

[image: sales table]

I applied the following request:

```
SELECT
    brand,
    segment,
    SUM (quantity)
FROM
    sales
GROUP BY
    CUBE (brand, segment)
ORDER BY
    brand,
    segment;
```

This error message appears:

```
ERROR:  function cube(text, text) does not exist
LINE 8:     CUBE (brand, segment)
            ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

********** Erreur **********

ERROR: function cube(text, text) does not exist
État SQL :42883
Astuce : No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
Caractère : 79
```

As far as i know, the version 9.5 supports `cube`.
What could be the source of this error?

Comment: What is the output of `select version()`?

Comment: This is the output `PostgreSQL 9.4.18 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-55), 64-bit` , What should i do to make it work ? Knowing that if i apply `psql --version` on my ubuntu terminal i get `postgresql 9.5.13`

Comment: `psql --version` gives you the version of `psql` (the sql client), not the version of the **server**

Comment: Thank you so much. Is that any way to make CUBE work for 9.4.18 version ?

Comment: No you cannot? However you should take a look at what horse has done for me! It can help!
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50581829/how-to-create-columns-for-different-fields-without-applying-the-pivoting-functio
and 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50605639/part-2-how-to-get-the-sum-of-a-partition-based-query-without-actually-pivoting